# remove certain parts of a url

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a small script that creates a url

```
<a href="index.php?username=<?php echo $user['name']; ?>" >View Profile</a>
```

The problem is the url shows

```
http://pimpedryde.com/cars/index.php?username=bimmerguy
```

I was wanting the url to look more like

```
http://pimpedryde.com/cars/bimmerguy
```

I've tried a few htaccess codes without success. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of code igniter Project, Try this one.

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, Vicky Gill but it didn't work. `authz_core_module` gave 403 errors. The `mod_rewrite` didn't make any changes to the url.

Comment: Its Require permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^http://pimpedryde.com/cars/(.*)=(.*)$ http://pimpedryde.com/cars/$2 [R=301,L]
```

**OR**

```
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)=(.*)$ http://pimpedryde.com/cars/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Brum. I still can't get this thing to work properly. I'm checking to see if the htaccess in the top DIR is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

This is a great little tool for testing: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

You are in a sub-folder, so you need the RewriteBase clause, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cars/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

That should do it.

Comment: Please vote up and select the answer as having solved the issue... it will be helpful for future coders having the same issue :)

Comment: Wish I could. I'm under 15 points. Don't worry, as soon as I can I'll up vote.